# mod_rewrite, links, virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

It seems that I'll never get along with mod_rewrite...
I'm in the typical scenario:

```
homepage_one.tld/impressum.php --> domain.tld?content=impressum
homepage_one.tld/projects.php --> domain.tld?content=projects
homepage_one.tld/projects/canvas.php --> domain.tld?content=projects&project=canvas
```

I'm developing offline, using Ubuntu Server Edition on an VMware. That means, the local domain for my homepage_one to test is: _http:///localhost:2180/homepage_one/index.php
Later it will be _http://homepage_one.tld.

```
 <Directory /var/www/homepage_one>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ index.php?content=$1 [QSA,L]
                RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)\.php$ index.php?content=projects&project=$1 [QSA,L]
        </Directory>
```

All **css** / **image links** are **broken ** now, when I'm asking for the url: _http://localhost:2180/homepage_one/projects/canvas.php
(It looks for "homepage_one/*projects*/canvas/style.css" instead of "homepage_one/style.css"

most answers at stackoverflow concerning this issue are: use **absolute links**. I tried it, but to test it offline, my absolute link would be /homepage_one/style.css and i would have to change ALL links, once I publish the website. I also tried to use the html-base tag. But this didn't work eigther.... any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you have some more rewrite rules. So, do post them.

Comment: no, that's it. Actually http://localhost:2180/homepage_one/projects.php is working perfect fine. I only have problems with the additional directory, when i'm using 2 parameters, since my browser doesn't know that this dir is just "fake"

Comment: add another rewrite rule pointing to the proper directory for linked files such as images and stylesheets.
So if you have:

`homepage_one.tld/projects/canvas.php --> domain.tld?content=projects&project=canvas`
Add:

`homepage_one.tld/projects/([^/.]+).css --> domain.tld/path/to/your/css/$1.css`

This might not be 100% correct, been a while since I've set mine up.
Have a read through : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: tahnks, you're right, that would solve the problem - but it would also double the number of rewrite rule, but I wanted to avoid that actually. Is there a possibility no create a rule like "if none of the rules before matched, put 'homepage_one' before the request uri"? (So I would have this rule just offline to correct the base-path and i would use absolute links)

Comment: It's years since I've used VMware as I use [VBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) these days, but you can configure your VM to have its own IP so you don't need to use host port fowarding. and then just add an entry in your `etc/hosts` for `domain.vm` and now you're testing against `http://domain.vm/...`  Keep the VM as close to target as poss.  See [this article](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-61) as an example.

Comment: Also is your target a cloudVM in which case using a vhost config is the right way to go, otherwise if it is a shared hosting solution, then you should be using an `.htaccess`-based solution as you won't have access to a vhost config on the target.

Comment: @TerryE sound like the best reasonable solution - this way I would have to use absolute links. I'm also working with Oracles VirtualBox - getting confused sometimes.

Comment: I would like to use vHost, that's what I also do on my online server. Do you have any tutorials, concerning the forwarding of an adress like domain1.vm to the virtual machine? I'm running a windows7 host sytem at the moment. Am I right, that I'd have to change some DNS entries? Or how should my Network adapter know, it should forward to the local VM? (if I'm not using port forwarding)

Comment: Never mind, I got it :) I didn't know that editing the hosts in windows is that easy, since I usually work with linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (thanks to @TerryE):

```
Edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc resp. /etc/hosts (linux)
127.0.0.1  my_homepage1.vm
127.0.0.1  my_homepage2.vm
```

in my case, using port forwarding to different VM's, I can reach them, as followed:

```
my_homepage1.vm:2180 --> VM1
my_homepage1.vm:2280 --> VM2
```

now I can just use VirtualHosts, as on my production Server, and go with **absolute links**.

Answer (score 1):

Johannes this is really an answer to your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254740/mod-rewrite-links-virtual-hosts#9271453) :-) The conventional way to list entries is `IP name name`, e.g.

```
127.0.0.1  localhost mysite.vm subdomain.mysite.vm blog.mysite.vm
```

or whatever.

I also find port forwarding a total pain.  I always use a bridged or host-only network.  My Windows/WMware skills are a bit rusty as I gave up on both about 5 years ago, but [this VMware page](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html) describes how to do it if you are using VMware Workstation.  You can do the same with a VMware appliance but you have to start tweaking the VMX file.  As I said in my blog article, which I recommend that you read, I find just easier with VBox.

In a bridged network, if you host NIC's MAC address is 00:23:18:dd:88:88 and your VM's is 08:00:27:FE:FE:FE then the VMware network driver programs the host NIC to respond to both but then passes the  08:00:27:FE:FE:FE packets onto the VM's virtual NIC. Hence the VM participates on the network just like any other PC and looks like a PC/server to any other devices.  I run all my home devices on a 192.168.1.0/24 private address space, so I just statically allocate IPs for my VMs in 192.168.1.192/26.

The great advantage of bridged and host-only networks is that you can use the default port 80, and that if you want you can also (temporarily) override your DNS entry for your myprodsite.com to point to your VM, so that any absolute coded `http://myprodsite.com/` URIs will then point back to the VM during testing.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: puh... this totally helps a lot. I've never configured a bridged network before; actually I was happy no make the port forwarding work to my virtual server. Thank's, I guess I'll try this on the weekend, so I don't have to use the 'total pain' port forwarding ;)

Comment: If it totally helps a +1 or a tick might be nice ;-)